# Dropping 'draggable' elements into a 'sortable' list causes problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm trying to move elements from one list to another by drag-n-drop. The source list is 'draggable', the target list is 'sortable'. There is a 'spinner' on every `<input>` inside the draggable elements.
Moving an element from one list to another causes a jquery error in the console `TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined` as you can see in jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/83YdD/ . After moving an element to the other list, the spinner is not working.

The javascript code:

```
$('.spinner').spinner();

$('#TasksOfDay > li').draggable({ connectToSortable: '#UserTasksOfDay' });

$('#UserTasksOfDay').sortable();
```

Example on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83YdD/

Any idea to solve this problem appreciated :-)

Comment: will have to reinitialize plugin after drop. Events bound to elements are lost when they get pulled from dom and reinserted

Comment: @charlietfl - you're right regarding the spinner event. But I still haven't get rid of the jquery error in the console. May be you have an idea, what's going on there?

Comment: I don't see any  error thrown in demo

Comment: are you using firebug?